# Optimizing structural overhead for videos processed by Encoding.com

Tags: video-streaming, video-encoding, http-live-streaming

Running the mediastreamvalidator tool on some HLS videos (MPEG-TS files indexed by M3U8's) we had processed by Encoding.com, we found a pretty high structural overhead on our files especially on low-medium bitrates. While this is not atypical, we were quite surprised to find some sites able to reduce overheads to the range of 3%.

Figures from tests on our files below:

Resolution-Bitrate : 416x234-200k
Playlist Syntax: OK
Segments:   OK
Average segment duration: 5.18 seconds
Segment bitrate: Average: 295.69 kbits/sec, Max: 295.69 kbits/sec

### Average segment structural overhead: 97.15 kbits/sec (32.86 %)

Resolution-Bitrate : 416x234-400k
Playlist Syntax: OK
Segments:   OK
Average segment duration: 5.18 seconds
Segment bitrate: Average: 467.74 kbits/sec, Max: 467.74 kbits/sec

### Average segment structural overhead: 94.16 kbits/sec (20.13 %)

Resolution-Bitrate : 640x360-600k
Playlist Syntax: OK
Segments:   OK
Average segment duration: 5.18 seconds
Segment bitrate: Average: 614.84 kbits/sec, Max: 614.84 kbits/sec

### Average segment structural overhead: 105.48 kbits/sec (17.16 %)

Resolution-Bitrate : 960x540-1800k
Playlist Syntax: OK
Segments:   OK
Average segment duration: 5.18 seconds
Segment bitrate: Average: 1.59 Mbits/sec, Max: 1.59 Mbits/sec

### Average segment structural overhead: 135.62 kbits/sec (8.52 %)

Resolution-Bitrate : 1280x720-2500k
Playlist Syntax: OK
Segments:   OK
Average segment duration: 5.18 seconds
Segment bitrate: Average: 2.16 Mbits/sec, Max: 2.16 Mbits/sec
Average segment structural overhead: 149.46 kbits/sec (6.93 %)

---

While I'm sure it's perfectly possible to achieve such a level of optimization (just 3% overhead at practically all bitrates) with a custom encoding setup using ffmpeg and the like, I'm wondering if there are any options available in the API calls to an off-the-shelf provider like Encoding.com, to reduce such overhead

Sorry if this is a bone-headed question, just asking out of ignorance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bone headed question.  Most open source ts packagers have this level of overhead.  Zencoder uses a customs built internal packager that averages between 4-6% overhead and is basically the same level of optimization found in apples media file segmenter.  There are no off the shelf settings for encoding.com that can achieve that level of performance.

Comment: Aww. Too bad. We were leaning towards Zencoder earlier in development but had to switch to Encoding due to some issues. Bit too late in the cycle now. But thanks!